# UIWebView underside

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to change the color of the gray underside of the UIWebView that's seen when the page is overscrolled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set the `backgroundColor` property.
Below I mentioned swift 3 syntax, currently instead of Color, Xcode is providing color plate for mentioning color

```
webview.backgroundColor = Color.white
```

Comment: Did you try this?  webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whitwColor]; does not work for me

Comment: You may need to post your code, because setting the background color as described here works fine (at least in 2.2.1).

Comment: Wow, this is odd. Setting the background color in the IB didn't seem to work, but doing it in code had the desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: Adding self.myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; just replaced the dark grey gradient with a light white/grey gradient.   Is there a way to set the overscrolled area to a flat solid color?

Comment: Got the same behavior like Bogatyr

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
for(UIView* subview in [self.webView1 subviews]){
  if([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]){
    [subview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  }
  for(UIView* imageView in [subview subviews]){
    if([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
      imageView.hidden = YES;
    }
  }
}
```