# Workaround for 'background-attachment: fixed' which is not working in iOS4

Tags: iphone, css, ios, ios4

I'm struggling to get web page with a fixed background image, so the image does not move when page is scrolled in a UIWebView.
What I've discovered is: `background-attachment: fixed` does not work in iOS4 (using 4.2.1). 
To double-check I've prepared a page with code snippet (below) inside `<head>` section and the page works as expected under Safari and Firefox on Mac, but fails to do so in iPhone's Safari...

What do you suggest as a workaround for achieving the expected results? I've made my UIWebView translucent and added UIImageView, so I can see "fixed background image" through translucent page. Unfortunately, I can see UIWebView borders when I scroll over its  end/beginning edges.

Is there any official Apple resource/web page stating that `background-attachment: fixed` is not implemented for iOS4?

Cheers!

P.S. The code snippet referred above:

```
<style type="text/css">  
body {  
    background: #ffffff url('image.jpg') fixed no-repeat;  
    background-attachment: fixed;  
}  
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is going on with the CSS and have not had a chance to check it out for myself but I know when I was trying to get rid of the shadows from a UIWebView I used this bit of code:

```
NSArray *sv = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[myWebView subviews]];
UIScrollView *webScroller = (UIScrollView *)[sv objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *wsv = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[webScroller subviews]];

[[wsv objectAtIndex:6] setHidden:YES];
[[wsv objectAtIndex:7] setHidden:YES];
[[wsv objectAtIndex:8] setHidden:YES];
[[wsv objectAtIndex:9] setHidden:YES];
```

and it got rid of the shadows.  I thought I got the answer off of a SO question but when I looked for it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074320/remove-uiwebview-shadow) is the only one that came up.

It passed App Store inspection.

Comment: Great tip! It worked and is a legitimate solution :) Tested in on iOS 4.2 (iPhone 4) and 3.1.3 (iPhone 3G). Only thing that can spoil the show is Apple changing something in view hierarchy, so I changed the code a bit to this: made a for-each for subviews and `if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])` is true, I set the property `hidden` to true. Thank you Andrew!

Answer (score 1):

Use a div for the background with a negative z-index:

```
<head>
<style>
#background {
    background: url("background.jpg") no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: 320px 480px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="background"></div>

This body text appears over the fixed background and scrolls.

</body>
```

Works on iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Comment: This was an ok solution when all iPhones had the same aspect ratio. But that's no longer the case. Any good solutions across all iOS devices?