# fixed background UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workaround for 'background-attachment: fixed' which is not working in iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991916/workaround-for-background-attachment-fixed-which-is-not-working-in-ios4)

I have a problem, there is a way for fix the background on UIWebView with css?
thank you

kikko088

Comment: What do you mean by fixing the background? A CSS background should already have a fixed non-draggable position...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but you can inject javascript into a UIWebView page.

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview

In theory you could just call document.write to write any html you need. If you have control over the html/css file, you could just add

```
<style type="text/css">
body  
{
background-image:url('smiley.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
</style>
```

Comment: the problem is that "background-attachment:fixed;" not work...:( I can modify html/css!

Comment: I have also tried using the css code suggested - the background still scrolls if you scroll the UIWebview (the desired effect is that the content scrolls over the top of the static image). The css seems valid - it just doesn't quite seem to work on the iPhone version of the browser - are there any workarounds?