# Shadows on UIWebview

Tags: ios6, uiwebview

I have a number of `UIWebView` objects which are all different colours and hold text that is formatted using html. When you scroll all the way to the bottom, or pull the text from the top, there are shadow lines at the top and bottom of the actual `UIWebView` frame, and also at the top and bottom of the text frame.

I have set the background colour of the `UIWebView` and `bgcolor` of the html text to be the same but I would really like to remove these shadows so the whole frame is consistently. In the picture the shadows I am referring to are the one just above the text and the one at the top of the view.

[image: shadows]

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009063/remove-gradient-background-from-uiwebview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove UIWebView Shadow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074320/remove-uiwebview-shadow)