# Remove the shadow of the webview

Tags: ios, webview, shadow, rubymotion

I would remove the shadow that is visible when you drag up and down on a sheet webview ?.
Because I find it

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) { 
   [[[[[maWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:x] setHidden:YES]; 
}
```

but I do not know how adaptader in ruby ​​ruby with motion

```
(0..10).each do|v|

end
```

this part of the code or I struggle to put it into ruby with rubymotion

```
[[[[[maWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:x] setHidden:YES];
```

thanks

Comment: in case if a person wants to do the same @web_view.subviews[0].subviews.each do|v|
      if v.isKindOfClass(UIImageView)
        v.setHidden(true)
      end
    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like:

```
maWebView.subviews[0].subviews.each {|view| view.setHidden(true)}
```

Or, if you really want to take only views from index 0 to 9:

```
(0...10).each{|x| maWebView.subviews[0].subviews[x].setHidden(true)}
```

Comment: it works a little closer, because deletes me all my views and I would just deleted the shadow of the webview. how? and what it can do?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074320/remove-uiwebview-shadow), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009063/remove-gradient-background-from-uiwebview), maybe, can help you.