# How to remove grey shadow on the top UIWebView when overscroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using UIWebView for show a simple HTML page. When I scroll the page (over the top or over the bottom) a shadow gray appears behind!!
Can I remove or avoid this bad effect?

Thx

P.S.
UIWebView, View container, are all background clear and opaque NO!!

Comment: Why have they put this stupid shadow in and not provided a means to remove it is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible! Over the web there are some solution that using private apple methods (undocumented api & functions). So, apple could **refuse** your app.

Comment: Did you try my code? I don't see why Apple would deny it or have a way to detect it since it's not calling any private apis.

Comment: Your solution is good! I try it early. I referer to other solutions founded on Web.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655225/uiwebview-underside

Answer (score 23):

The shadows are of class `UIImageView`. You can loop through the views of the first subview of `UIWebView` and just hide any views that match `UIImageView`.

```
id scrollview = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];    
for (UIView *subview in [scrollview subviews])
  if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
   subview.hidden = YES;
```

Disclaimer: the view hierarchy could change in the future and this would not work causing the shadows to come back.

Comment: i put your code on the viewDidLoad , and doesn't work .

Comment: [subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] would be more correct, but the proper answer is given by Undolog.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it to be "more correct". :)

Comment: There's also no need for the first line, since you can access the `scrollView` directly, so the loop could be changed to: `for (UIView *subview in [webView.scrollview subviews])`

Comment: The shadow is back with iOS 5

Comment: @zeiteisen I had the same problem with iOS 5.1 and removing the image views did not help. To solve the problem, I moved the web view up by about 4px so that the shadow ended up underneath the navigation bar. Moreover, I disabled bouncing of the scroll view (which is a public property of `UIWebView` in iOS 5).

Answer (score 5):

Check this out worked for me..

`UIScrollView *scrollview = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];`
    `scrollview.bounces=NO;`

Comment: that property is just webView.scrollView and just makes it so you can't scroll. You haven't removed the annoying shadow.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (UIView *view in self.webView.scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            view.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
```

Why Apple would be reject this method, there is no undocumented and private part :)
You find any view, check their class, and hide... 
You are not delete, or rewrite methods..
You not modified (rewrite) any parts of object... only hide, No ?

Comment: I think this is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

put uiwebview on uiscrollview and disable uiwebview scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 and out a nice UIImageView at the background.

This is simple and easy.

Comment: the shadow will still remain

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id subview in _webView.subviews)
            if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {
                for (UIView *scrollSubview in [subview subviews])
                    if ([[scrollSubview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                        scrollSubview.hidden = YES;
            }
```

This solution will not be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in this situation where scrolling is not required, because all your content fits, calling the sizeToFit method on the UIWebView will eliminate these shadows.