# Is it possible to remove ["Page 1 of 20" view] in a UIwebview when displaying pdf?

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I can not get to a solution after much googling.
I have a UIWebView with a PDF in it.

I do not want the view: "Page 1 of 20" The small view in the upper left corner when viewing a PDF file.
It is possible to remove this?

Comment: page number hint doesn't look like JS thing. You can take a look on similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4167060/729175 You can try to walk through hidden .subviews and find what you want.

Comment: while this could be possible to achieve via traversing the subviews, it isn't a very elegant solution. In my opinion it would be beetter to use a dedicated iOS PDF Reader Component like PSPDFKit(commercial), vfrreader or FastPDFKit to name a few

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 3 and `WKWebView`**

I get all the subviews of the `WKWebView` and then remove `WKPDFPageNumberIndicator`:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  let webViewSubviews = self.getSubviewsOfView(v: self.webView)
  for v in webViewSubviews {
    if v.description.range(of:"WKPDFPageNumberIndicator") != nil {
      v.isHidden = true // hide page indicator in upper left
    }
  }
}

func getSubviewsOfView(v:UIView) -> [UIView] {
  var viewArray = [UIView]()
  for subview in v.subviews {
    viewArray += getSubviewsOfView(v: subview)
    viewArray.append(subview)
  }
  return viewArray
}
```

You'll probably have to set `webView.navigationDelegate = self`

**UPDATE (not tested) - Swift 4**

Keep the `getSubviewsOfView` function from above and modify the webView function like this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  let webViewSubviews = self.getSubviewsOfView(v: self.webView)
  for v in webViewSubviews {
    if v.isKind(of: UILabel.self) || v.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) || v.isKind(of: UIVisualEffectView.self) {
      v.isHidden = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MassimoPolimeni it's been a long time so it's possible that the WKPDFPageNumberIndicator has been renamed in newer versions of swift. I don't have a project that I could quickly run to test this out and help you :/ Try going through all the subviews and hiding all the UIImageView, UILabel and UIVisualEffectView as some other answers suggest.

Comment: @MassimoPolimeni check out the modification I did above and please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I changed a little bit to match Swift 4.2 syntax so placing `v.isKind(of: UILabel.self)` but it still doesn't work, not sure why I'm debugging it, the main idea seems legitimate

Comment: I remember that I basically printed out `v.description` for all the subviews and then I detected something containing `WKPDFPageNumberIndicator`. Good luck ;)

Comment: Not work :/. Not able to find `WKPDFPageNumberIndicator` class. iOS 13.3 Using `WKWebview`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working on iOS9, 10 (tested)

```
    func hidePageNumberView(v: UIView) {
        for subView in v.subviews {
            if subView.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) || subView.isKindOfClass(UILabel) || subView.isKindOfClass(UIVisualEffectView){
                subView.hidden = true

                if subView.isKindOfClass(UILabel) {
                    if let sv = subView.superview {
                        sv.hidden = true
                    }
                }
            } else {
                hidePageNumberView(subView)
            }
        }
    }
```

Implement `webView.scrollView.delegate` and run above code in `scrollViewDidScroll`

Hope this help.

**iOS 11 / Swift 4:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    hidePageNumberView(scrollView)
}

func hidePageNumberView(_ v: UIView) {
    for subView in v.subviews {
        if subView is UIImageView || subView is UILabel || subView is UIVisualEffectView {
            subView.isHidden = true

            if subView is UILabel {
                if let sv = subView.superview {
                    sv.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        } else {
            hidePageNumberView(subView)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a while I've found a solution using swift 5 and WKWebView together with my partner:

```
let pdfWebView: WKWebView = {
     let webView = WKWebView()
     webView.backgroundColor = .clear
     webView.isOpaque = false
     webView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
     return webView
}()

pdfWebView.delegate = self
pdfWebView.navigationDelegate = self

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     guard let last = webView.subviews.last else {
          return
     }

     last.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to your question...
You can Hide the "Page 1 of 20" using following code :

```
for (UIView* subView in [webView subviews])
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        for (UIView* shadowView in [subView subviews])
        {
            if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                [shadowView setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this may be helpful to some one...
Thanks...