# How remove or hide page counter of PDF from WKWebview?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, pdf, wkwebview

How i can remove or hide a page counter from `WKWebview` when load a PDF file?

[image: f]

I tried the solutions that are on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219562/is-it-possible-to-remove-page-1-of-20-view-in-a-uiwebview-when-displaying-pd) (using iOS 13.3, Swift 4.2.), but they don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of a friend, we found a solution.
 
In the delegate method, we can hide the `UIView` which contains the page counter:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    hidePDFPageCount(webView)
}

func hidePDFPageCount(_ webView: WKWebView){
    guard let last = webView.subviews.last else {
        return
    }

    last.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: this implementation breaks the content when dealing with html files

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C version, tested on iOS 14:

```
#pragma mark - WKNavigationDelegate

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    UIView *lastView = webView.subviews.lastObject;
    
    if (lastView != nil && ![lastView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        lastView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Compared to the accepted answer I had to add:

```
![lastView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]
```

Because the last view is not always the page counter.